# What permission do I need for getting organization of a user?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get our app onboarded to Microsoft Graph, in our application we are only sending request for getting user tenants' geolocations:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization?$select=countryLetterCode,state
```

I am wondering what's the permission I need to claim? I checked [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/organization_get.md) page, but it's written "unavailable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this - this is a doc a bug.  I've filed this here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2015

Hope this helps,

Comment: Permissions have been added to this page now.